# Sort ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> by Unix time-stamp

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to sort the data inside `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` by Unix time-stamp. 
I have 2 arraylists and I merge them: `arraylist1.addall(arraylist2);`. But I am unable to sort the data inside by Unix time-stamp descending (newest first).

Arraylist 1:

```
[{id=1, name=Aa, time=1394500000},
 {id=2, name=Ab, time=1394500001},
 {id=3, name=Ac, time=1394500002}]
```

Arraylist 2;

```
[{id=1, name=AA, time=1394500001},
 {id=2, name=AA, time=1394500000},
 {id=3, name=Ac, time=1394500005}]
```

I really appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First, if you have a `List<Map<>>` you are likely doing something wrong - use objects. Second, you're going to need to provide a little more detail than random string representations which don't make sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry adding entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a better idea to create a class to hold these attributes.

```
class MyData {    
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private long time;

  //all other stuff
}
```

Then just use an `ArrayList<MyData>` and sort it using `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator.

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyData>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(MyData o1, MyData o2) {
            return Long.compare(o1.getTime(), o2.getTime());  
        }
};
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(arraylist1, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1, HashMap<String, String> o2) {
                String value1 =  o1.get("time");
                String value2 =  o2.get("time");
                return Long.compare(Long.valueOf(value1).longValue(), Long.valueOf(value2).longValue()); 
                
            }
        });`

Comment: @jason Yes (assuming each map as a mapping `"time" -> "value"`), but I highly recommend you tu use a class to perform this task, as it is a far better OO approach. Also the last line can be simplified as `return Long.valueOf(value1).compareTo(Long.valueOf(value2));`

Comment: @ZouZou or [`Long.compare(value1, value2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,%20long)).

Comment: @BoristheSpider `value1` and `value2` are `String`, not `long`.

Comment: @ZouZou gotcha - thought you were talking about your example code.